# Query works on localhost,but not on server

Tags: php, function

im trying to update fields,so when im on localhost it does everything succesfully,but when im on server it does nothing.Here's code:

```
 if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$update_data = array(

'total_kills'            => $total_kills,
'total_deaths'           => $total_deaths,
'total_assists'          => $total_assists,
'highest_champ_dmg'      => $highest_champ_dmg,

'times_played'           => $times_played,
'wins'                   => $wins,
'losses'                 => $losses,
'win_rate'               => $win_rate,
'record_total_dmg'       => $record_total_dmg,
'total_kda'              => $total_kda,
'average_kills'          => $average_kills,
'average_deaths'         => $average_deaths,
'average_assists'        => $average_assists,
'average_kda'            => $average_kda,
'highest_kills'          => $highest_kills,
'highest_deaths'         => $highest_deaths,
'highest_assists'        => $highest_assists,
'highest_kda'            => $highest_kda,
'lowest_kills'           => $lowest_kills,
'lowest_deaths'          => $lowest_deaths,
'lowest_assists'         => $lowest_assists,
'lowest_kda'             => $lowest_kda
);


foreach($update_data as $field=>$data){
        $update = '`' . $field .'` = \'' . $data . '\'';
        $dbc->query("UPDATE `champions` SET ".implode(', ',array($update)) ."WHERE `name`='$champ_name'");
    }
}




if(!$_SESSION['Username'] == ""){
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Update" name="update">';
}
```

Is there something i should know,that affects,code when it's being hosted?

Comment: Step one: [Enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/).

Comment: Error reporting for php is not the same as errors for mysql? Have you used `mysql_error()`?

Comment: Maybe you should check your permission. Are the login credentials correct?

Comment: Every other query works,problem is somewhere here =/

Comment: And mysql_error() didnt give anything.

Answer (score 0):

Update row like this:

```
$update = '`' . $field .'` = '\' . $data . '\'';
```

Comment: It gave me 2 errors now on screen: Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 on query line and: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING also on query line.